# Error in calendar booking system

Tags: php, calendar, wamp

I have a 'calendar booking system' in PHP and below are code snippets of that.
I am running WampServer2.4

```
<?
include('php/connect.php'); 
include('classes/class_calendar.php');

$calendar = new booking_diary($link);

if (isset($_GET['month'])) $month = $_GET['month']; else $month = date("0");
if (isset($_GET['year'])) $year = $_GET['year']; else $year = date("0");
if (isset($_GET['day'])) $day = $_GET['day']; else $day = 0;

$selected_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 01, $year); // Make a timestamp based on the GET values
$first_day = date("N", $selected_date) - 1; // Gives numeric representation of the day of the week 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)
$back = strtotime("-1 month", $selected_date);
$forward = strtotime("+1 month", $selected_date);

?>
```

And

```
<?php     

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $calendar->after_post($month, $day, $year);  
}   

// Call calendar function
$calendar->make_calendar($selected_date, $first_day, $back, $forward, $day, $month, $year);

?>
```

And the function is

```
function make_calendar($selected_date, $first_day, $back, $forward, $day, $month, $year) {

    // Add a value to these public variables  
    $this->day = $day;    
    $this->month = $month;
    $this->year = $year;

    $this->selected_date = $selected_date;    
    $this->first_day = $first_day;

    $this->back = $back;
    $this->back_month = date("m", $back);
    $this->back_year = date("Y", $back); // Minus one month back arrow

    $this->forward = $forward;
    $this->forward_month = date("m", $forward);
    $this->forward_year = date("Y", $forward); // Add one month forward arrow    

    // Make the booking array
    $this->make_booking_array($year, $month);
```

}

But when I try to run the code, I am getting this annoying error.

> > Notice: Undefined variable: calendar in C:\wamp\www\calendar\calendar.php on line 42
> >
> > Fatal error: Call to a member function make_calendar() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\calendar\calendar.php on line 42

Can anyone tell where I am getting wrong in my script.

Answer (score 2):

where your function `make_calendar()` is defined? According to your code, it should be in booking_diary class

Comment: it is defined in the booking_diary class

Comment: If I send you all files can you check it out?

Comment: you can update your question with more detailed code. (remove unrelated parts)